# How can I print some string until a command finishes?

Tags: bash, scp, nginx

I use a bash script to download a large file from a client device into a web server.

But since it will take a large amount of time, nginx will return gateway timeout. What i plan to do is pass the stdout of bash script to a python subprocess and send it as response. Since scp will not produce any output in stdout, I need to send some response every minute until `scp` command finishes.

Is there any way to achieve this using bash script?

Also I cannot increase Nginx timeout since it will usually take more than 20 minutes

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  I am having trouble understanding where exactly in the stack you need help.  You have mentioned both the client and the server, where and how do you need help?

Comment: nginx when used as a proxy have a timeout if no response is received from the server within a time and it gives a 504 gateway timeout error. so to avoid it i have to send something in every predefined time interval when i have to make the client wait until a big file is downloaded in the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spawn a process that does some output in the background and kill it once `scp` is done:

```
(while sleep 60; do echo downloading; done) &
PID=$!
scp "$1" "$2"
kill $PID
```

Comment: this one looks more efficient for my need

Answer (score 2):

Here is more general function to handle download and wait:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Wait for process end and show seconds count down
# Arg1: PID
# Arg2: Expected seconds
# Arg3: (optional): dump file
# Arg4: (optional): expected file size in bytes
function waitpid() {
[ -n "$3" ] && touch "$3"
local COUNT=$(( $2*10 ))
while [ -e /proc/$1 ]; do 
    if [ $(( COUNT%10 )) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -en "\r$(( COUNT/10 )) sec"
        if [ -n "$3" ]; then
            bytes=$( stat --format=%s $3 )
            echo -n " $bytes bytes "
            if [ -n "$4" ]; then
                echo -n "$(( $bytes*100/$4 ))% "
            fi
        fi
    fi
    echo -en ".\e[K"
    sleep 0.1
    [ $COUNT -gt 0 ] && COUNT=$(( COUNT-1 ))
done
echo
}

echo "Example 1: Wait for process to be finished"
sleep 10 &
waitpid $! 10

echo "Example 2: Wait and show file size"
for N in {1..5} ; do echo "BAR $N" >> /tmp/foo ; sleep 2 ; done &
waitpid $! 10 /tmp/foo
```

Example output:

```
Example 1: Wait for process to be finished
3 sec........
Example 2: Wait and show file size
7 sec 160 bytes .......
```

Edit: If too complex use the short version:

```
sleep 10 &
while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do echo -n . ; sleep 1 ; done
```

Screen shot:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 5432
$ while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do echo -n . ; sleep 1 ; done
..........[1]+  Done sleep 10
```

Comment: nice one, recommended for general use. but i just have to echo something. no need for much complexity

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally did it, I pass arguments `$1` and and `$2` for `scp`, here I get the process id of `scp` command and until it finishes I echo the response downloading in every one minute. 
For this I use `SECONDS` in bash

```
t=$SECONDS
scp $1 $2 &
PROC_ID=$!
while kill -0 "$PROC_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    n=$(( SECONDS-t))
    if (( n > 60 )); then
        echo downloading
        t=$SECONDS
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is *very* busy polling. You should add a `sleep` in at the end of the loop to avoid hogging the CPU.

Comment: @kmkaplan how much time, if i add sleep even if download finished it will again sleep until that time finishes right?

Comment: It depends, maybe 1 second, but anything between 100ms and 10s depending on personal preference.  PS. On GNU, you can sleep just a fraction of second, eg. `sleep 0.5`.  But other implementations of sleep(1) only accept integer arguments.

Comment: @HaseebEqx yes. A good start would be a one second sleep. But see my answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350027/26432) to do it the other way round.